# Finding CRC for a pocket of data

Tags: crc

I'm trying to find the method and polynomial that used in a packet of data like that:

00 00 41 xx xx yy yy ............................ ff
The first bytes (00 00 41) is a magic number that is used at the beginning of each data block.
xx xx is the block data #.
yy yy is the saved CRC-16.
Then we have 512 bytes (in Hex) of data.
The block ends with FF.
I try to use CRC reveng, but my main problem is how should I consider the data packet to feed in CRC RevEng? I know that block number affects the CRC.

Please guide me.

I need to know if I consider 00 00 41 and ff in feed data? Shall I put block number before 512 byte data or after?